# How to make 1:52 to 01:52 with eg.: sed?

Tags: sed, date

INPUT:

```
a|2013.06.13. 13:22|xx
b|2013.06.13. 1:52 |xx
c|2013.06.13. 2:26 |xx
```

OUTPUT:

```
a|2013.06.13. 13:22|xx
b|2013.06.13. 01:52 |xx
c|2013.06.13. 02:26 |xx
```

How can I make the 1:52 to 01:52 in this case?

UPDATE: Thanks! These are working great, but how can I remove the space between the minutes and the "|" if 0 were added?

```
$ sed -e 's/ \([0-9]:\)/ 0\1/' b.txt 
a|2013.06.13. 13:22|xx
b|2013.06.13. 01:52 |xx
c|2013.06.13. 02:26 |xx
$ perl -wpe 's/(\d+):/sprintf( "%02d:",$1)/e' b.txt 
a|2013.06.13. 13:22|xx
b|2013.06.13. 01:52 |xx
c|2013.06.13. 02:26 |xx
$
```

wow.. :)

Comment: Do you really want to keep the trailing space, though?  It would seem better to force all the time stamps to a consistent machine-readable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/ \([0-9]:\)/ 0\1/'
```

adds a zero if a single digit occurs between a space and a colon. If you also want to get rid of the space after the minutes, it's

```
sed -e 's/ \([0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\) / 0\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the number before the colon and print it as two digits with leadings zero:

```
perl -wpe 's/(\d+):/sprintf("%02d:",$1)/e'
```

To fix the space issue you can extend the expression a little bit:

```
perl -wpe 's/(\d+):(\d+) +\|/sprintf("%02d:%02d|",$1,$2)/e'
```

Or if you want to match only exactly your case:

```
perl -wpe 's/ (\d:\d\d) \|/ 0$1|/'
```

Comment: Wouldn't the first two be troublesome if the input happens to be zero-prepended already (e.g. `09:22`)? I can't test easily right now, but I would be worried about Perl seeing the literal e.g. `09` and trying to interpret that as an octal number because it is 0-prefixed.

Comment: No, perl will handle this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\b[0-9]:/0&/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

non-sed version:

```
$ cat sample.txt 
a|2013.06.13. 13:22|xx
b|2013.06.13. 1:52 |xx
c|2013.06.13. 2:26 |xx
c|2013.06.13. 2:6 |xx
$ while read l; do
>   IFS=" |:" read -a array <<< "$l"
>   printf "%s|%s %02s:%02s|%s\n" ${array[0]} ${array[1]} ${array[2]} ${array[3]} ${array[4]}
> done < sample.txt
a|2013.06.13. 13:22|xx
b|2013.06.13. 01:52|xx
c|2013.06.13. 02:26|xx
c|2013.06.13. 02:06|xx
```